# An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, mean-stack, node-modules

When I start to run my Application, I get this error:

```
**[error] Error: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.**
     at Observable._subscribe (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/jobs/simple-scheduler.js:350:23)
     at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
     at Observable.subscribe (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
     at /Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
     at Object.subscribeToResult (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
     at InnerSubscriber._next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
     at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
     at /Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:17:28
     at Object.subscribeToResult (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/vasil/KSS/kssfrontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
```

I have these versions:
`Angular CLI: 8.3.19`,
`Node: 12.14.0`.

Any Idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with @angular-devkit/build-angular.

Try updating it by running

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Or downgrading it by specifying a previous version, such as

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```

Comment: Updating the version didn't work for me, but downgrading to that specific one did it for me.

Comment: worked for me i checked package.json in my github and upgraded to following version npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.803.17  and it perfectly worked for me

Comment: for ionic 5 trying to add leaflet maps, build-angular in package.json was showing 0.900.1; that was causing the problem; downgrading to the other packages at 0.801.12 brought the high vulnerabilities back; downgrading to 0.803.24 worked.. no more vulnerabilities but was still working as ionic 5 shows won't work with 9.0 angular

Comment: This issue usually comes when we are installing an angular theme. For me, downgrading the version worked.

Comment: How this should be even useful? How one determines to which version downgrade???

LOL

Comment: For me, downgrading to 0.801.2 worked (i.e., npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.801.2). Thank you.

Comment: Try ng update @angular/cli @angular/core (answered by @ColemanTO)
It will update the angular project and fix this error

Comment: It can happen if you use `npm audit fix --force`. The following message speaks for itself: `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

Comment: Also work for me after downgrading to a lower version of angular

Comment: "npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24" it worked for me thanks.

Comment: Since everyone is mentioning specific versions that work for them, it might be helpful to point out that the library has tags that point to the latest supported version for your CLI version. If you are using Angular 8, you can upgrade to the latest compatible version with `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@v8-lts`, which is more likely to work than whatever version was latest a few months ago. See the "versions" tab at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular, but you can probably guess what tag is appropriate for your version.

Comment: Thanks so much "npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24" worked for me.

Answer (score 141):

I had this error after `npm audit` found vulnerabilities in the version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` that I was using. I ran `npm audit fix` which updated it to `0.900.2`, but when I ran `ng serve` it gave the error quoted in the question.

I resolved it by downgrading to version `0.803.25`. This was the highest version I could find which did not cause any errors when running `ng serve`. The vulnerabilities found by `npm audit` are resolved in this version.

This is the command I ran:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.25
```

Comment: Happened to me as well, needs more careful while running audit fix which actually breaks annoying though

Comment: I broke it two times with ```npm audit``` now I am ok with vulerabilities

Answer (score 50):

I had just created a new project and got this error. Since I had no legacy code I needed to work with and wanted to use the latest (9.0) version of Angular, I ran this command:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

and it fixed everything.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer since it addresses the most common use case of getting this error.

Answer (score 5):

update @angular-devkit/build-angular version .

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `package-lock.json` and reinstalling `node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Ionic 4 after running "npm audit fix", but npm broke the whole versioning of the dependencies.

I tried doing most of the things listed here but it would fix one problem and create a new one. So the only solution that worked for me was manual dependency handling.

Check out what versions of each package you need in your package.json and package-lock.json (which package version do other packages depend on and expect to find in your project, mine were expecting about three total versions of some files), some will be shown as warnings in your cli after npm installing some packages, but not all will show so do best to manually check. 
 **NB: I found package-lock.json easier for me to read but I would refer to package.json to make sure I was still on the right track.**

For me the main package was Ionic itself (@ionic/angular-toolkit was the only package I could find that was connected to angular), so I looked at the version of angular it was expecting and downgraded to that. Then every other package that angular needed also had to be checked. It was a lot of work and spent half a day fixing but it solved all my issues.

1. An ionic package had this [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImEGZ.jpg);

   - @schematics/angular@^8.0.0
   - tslib@^1.9.0
   - ws@^7.0.1

Focusing on the angular package, I decided to 
`npm install @schematics/angular@8.0.0`

2. That dependency, @schematics/angular@8.0.0, had the following [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh8FU.jpg);

   - @angular-devkit/core@8.0.0
   - @angular-devkit/schematics@8.0.0
3. The dependency, @angular-devkit/schematics@8.0.0 had the [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgjAW.jpg);

   - @angular-devkit/core@8.0.0
   - rxjs@6.4.0

I did this for all the packages until I could build my app again. But you can just install in one go if you know the versions they require 
`npm install @schematics/angular@8.0.0 @angular-devkit/core@8.0.0 @angular-devkit/schematics@8.0.0`

You can put all the packages in that npm install line if you already know for certain which other packages should be downgraded or upgraded to save time.

Hope this helps anyone who couldn't find a solution from the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing ngx-quill and faced the same issue.
please make sure to check the supported versions.

For example - If you are using Angular 8, make sure you are installing the supported version. In case of ngx-quill, it will be 
npm install ngx-quill@**5.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my ng8 project to ng9 with

```
ncu -u
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that, you should use ng update for migration

Answer (score 0):

running `ng update` will tell you what you need to update.
then run the commands and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using the below command.

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.801.2
```