# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Angular Web App builds and runs on Windows but fails on Mac OSX and in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created a basic ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web app from Angular template in Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 machine.  The entire project source code is located here

```
git clone https://erotavlas-1@bitbucket.org/dev-issues/webclient.git
```

When I build and run it on Windows machine it works fine and  launches correctly inside the Microsoft Edge browser.

However when I copied the project to my Macbook (OS Catalina) and was going to build it into a docker image, it fails to do so.  These are the messages at the end of the build

```
  > webclient@0.0.0 build /src/WebClient/ClientApp
  > ng build "--prod"

  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
  Killed
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 137
  npm ERR! webclient@0.0.0 build: `ng build "--prod"`
  npm ERR! Exit status 137
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the webclient@0.0.0 build script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-12T13_22_34_364Z-debug.log
/src/WebClient/WebClient.csproj(40,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code 137.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish "WebClient.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Then I thought maybe something was wrong with the project so I tried to open it in Visual Studio for Mac and it builds perfectly fine with no errors.  But when I run it it generates the following output in the Visual Studio output

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: sh: /Users/username/Documents/DEV/WebClient/WebClient/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/ng: Permission denied

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! webclient@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "59704"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webclient@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:


---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The Browser opens with the message

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: sh: /Users/username/Documents/DEV/WebClient/WebClient/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/ng: Permission denied

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! webclient@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "59704"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webclient@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

))
```

When I tried to build the docker image on Windows it also failed.

Any guidance with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some investigation on this issue using my Mac. Turns out I can build and run the docker container successfully after some modifications. You can check my detailed code changes [here](https://gitlab.com/bemn-proof-of-concept/so-45841902-playground).

I can successfully run it on Mac by running the following commands:

```sh
dotnet build
cd WebClient
dotnet run
```

#### 1. Removing `PublishRunWebpack` from csproj

When I tried to run the Dockerfile to build the image, I saw the same error as the problem described, which somehow leaded me to [this article](https://alakbarv.azurewebsites.net/2019/01/11/dockerize-asp-net-core-angular-application-solving-error-the-command-npm-install-exited-with-code-127/) and checked the `PublishRunWebpack` task in the `WebClient.csproj`:

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

  <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The `PublishRunWebpack` task will run when publishing the app (i.e. `dotnet publish ...`) and therefore **will not** be triggered under development (i.e. `dotnet run`), suggesting that `npm run build -- --prod` failed when building the Docker image or npm does not even exist in your building stage.

#### 2. Adding build stage in Dockerfile (for node)

Therefore, I removed that build target from `WebClient.csproj` and added a build stage in Dockerfile to build the Angular web app. **The following code segment shows the node build stage only** and [here is the complete Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/bemn-proof-of-concept/so-45841902-playground/-/blob/master/Dockerfile).

```
### some steps to build and publish the dotnet app...

#Angular build
FROM node as nodebuilder

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY WebClient/ClientApp/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
# (use 8.3.14 as I saw package.json is using this)
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.14 --unsafe

# add app
COPY WebClient/ClientApp/. /usr/src/app

## this is the original step stated in the .csproj file
RUN npm run build -- --prod

## or, you can use the following command if you enable server-side prerendering
# RUN npm run build:ssr -- --prod

### some steps to copy the Angular web app to ClientApp/dist/...
```

#### 3. Fixing Angular build errors

When I started to build the Docker image again, I met the following issues and got the solutions from Stack Overflow:

- **Job name “..getProjectMetadata” does not exist**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101207/13742790
- **Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator"**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781705/13742790

#### Build and run

After that, I can build and run the Docker image successfully at http://localhost:8080:

```sh
docker build . -t web-client
docker run -p 8080:80 -d web-client
```

[image: Running the dockerized app]

The dashboard shows the app is running:
[image: Docker dashboard]

Comment: "I removed that build target from WebClient.csproj" Is that the entire 'Target' node in the XML of csproj? Also I used the dockerfile from Step 2 and tested the app but never got any errors as described in Step 3.  Is that the final dockerfile?

Comment: @erotavlas yes you need to remove the `PublishRunWebpack` <Target> node. Removing that node will SKIP building the Angular app. 
Therefore, in the Dockerfile ([this one](https://gitlab.com/bemn-proof-of-concept/so-45841902-playground/-/blob/master/Dockerfile#L19)) I defined a stage (from line 19-40) to build the Angular client app.